# git-svn: Migrating a SVN repository with branches in different hierarchical levels

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm migrating a lot of Git repositories in my company and everything was fine until I faced a repository with a very specific layout for branches:

```
/trunk/
/branches/
/branches/lvl1branch1
/branches/lvl1branch2
/branches/lvl1branch3
/branches/lvl2/lvl2branch1
/branches/lvl2/lvl2branch2
/branches/lvl2/lvl2branch
/branches/lvl2/lvl3/lvl3branch1
/branches/lvl2/lvl3/lvl3branch2
/branches/lvl2/lvl3/lvl3branch3
/tags/
```

As you can see, we have branches not only in the top level of **/branches/** (e.g. **lvl1branch1**), but only in other two levels (e.g. **lvl2/lvl2branch1** and **lvl2/lvl3/lvl3branch3**).

This is my **.git/config**:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://myrepourl/
    fetch = test/trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
    branches = test/branches/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    branches = test/branches/lvl2/*:refs/remotes/origin/lvl2/*
    branches = test/branches/lvl2/*/*:refs/remotes/origin/lvl2/*/*
```

And I get this error when I try to run the **git svn fetch** command:

*fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/lvl2/lvl3/lvl3branch1': cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/lvl2/lvl3/lvl3branch1': 'refs/remotes/origin/lvl2/lvl3' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/lvl2/lvl3/lvl3branch1'
update-ref -m r1638 refs/remotes/origin/lvl2/lvl3/lvl3branch1 e421f7d976832aa2efe84da02378e7f89eb55c26: command returned error: 128*

I can see I can create the branch **lvl2/lvl3/lvl3branch1** because Git is considering **lvl2/lvl3** is a branch, which is not true. Probably the line below in .git/config is causing the problem:

```
branches = test/branches/RT-Delivery/*:refs/remotes/origin/lvl2/*
```

How can I tell Git to avoid reading **lvl2/lvl3** as a branch? I believe I will also face the same problem with **lvl2**, which is not a branch. Is there a way to add exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out a solution, we can use the wildcards (*) also for filtering the directory names. Here is the **.git/config**:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://svn.it.volvo.net/svn/rtdms_tools/
    fetch = test/trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
    branches = test/branches/lvl1*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    branches = test/branches/lvl2/lvl2*:refs/remotes/origin/lvl2/*
    branches = test/branches/lvl2/lvl3/*:refs/remotes/origin/lvl2/lvl3/*
```

For instance, in order to make sure we will only get the branches in the first level (the ones starting with "lvl1"), instead of

```
branches = test/branches/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

we can use

```
branches = test/branches/lvl1*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```